# Count how many rows within the same group have a larger value in a given column for each row in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with a group field and variable of interest. For each row in the dataframe I want to count how many rows within the same group have a larger value for the variable of interest.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['a',1],['a',2],['a',2],['a',3],['b',4],['b',2],['b',6]],
                  columns = ['groups','value'])
df
```

```
  groups value
0   a      1
1   a      2
2   a      2
3   a      3
4   b      4
5   b      2
6   b      6
```

Here is the output I'm hoping to receive:

```
  groups value what_i_want
0   a      1        3
1   a      2        1
2   a      2        1
3   a      3        0
4   b      4        1
5   b      2        2
6   b      6        0
```

I know I could get to this answer by looping through each row of the dataframe, however I also know iterating through the rows of dataframe is a last resort and my full dataset is much bigger and that would take a long time to run. I'm assuming there is some way to do this using groupby or apply, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC `rank`

```
(-df.value).groupby(df['groups']).rank(method='min')-1
Out[466]: 
0    3.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
6    0.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

#df['what i want']=(-df.value).groupby(df['groups']).rank(method='min')-1
```

Comment: Thanks, this will get me exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy broadcasting for each group:

```
def summarize(group):
    v = group['value'].values
    other = v[:, None]
    count = (other > v).sum(axis=0)

    return pd.DataFrame({'what_i_want': count})

df.groupby('groups').apply(summarize)
```

---

### Explanation

Let consider group `a`. We first extract the elements in `values` to a numpy array called `v`:

```
v = [1, 2, 2, 3] # ndarray of shape (4,)
```

We want to compare this array against itself orthogonally and count how many elements are greater than the current element. The `[:, None]` syntax is to raise `v` an extra dimension...

```
other = [[1], [2], [2], [3]] # ndarray of shape (4,1)
```

...so that the `other > v` operation is broadcastable and the comparison matrix looks like this:

```
other > v
            v:  [ 1   2   2   3 ]
other:  [
         [1]      F   F   F   F
         [2]      T   F   F   F
         [2]      T   F   F   F
         [3]      T   T   T   F
        ]
----------------------------------
sum(axis=0)       3   1   1   0
```

Comment: Thanks, this can get me what I need, although I think the other answer that use .rank() is a little simpler for this problem. I appreciate the step by step explanation it really helped me understand why it works and should be helpful knowledge if I have a similar, but more complex problem in the future where something like .rank() can't be used!